# dplyr - join two dataframes by date range condition

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to join two df by two conditions in R, the conditions are

- Same country code
- date between a range of dates

DF1

| CountryCode | EventDate |
| --- | --- |
| NL | 2023-02-17 |
| DE | 2022-08-17 |

| CountryCode | FreightCost | ValidFrom | ValidUntil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NL | 10 | 2021-07-01 | 2022-07-31 |
| NL | 12 | 2021-08-01 | 2025-12-31 |
| DE | 8 | 2021-08-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| DE | 11 | 2023-01-01 | 2025-12-31 |

I'm having issues using merge or a join function from dplyr

The desire output I would like to have is

| CountryCode | EventDate | FreightCost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NL | 2023-02-17 | 12 |
| DE | 2022-08-17 | 8 |

I have tried this, but unable to find a solution

```
DF_final <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(
    df2 ,
    by = join_by(
      CountryCode= CountryCode,
      between(EventDate,
              ValidFrom,
              ValidUntil)
    )
)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from your first variable in `by`. You should either use `==` or state it once since they have the same name in both data sets:

```r
df1 %>% 
  left_join(
    df2,
    by = join_by(
      CountryCode,
      between(EventDate,
              ValidFrom,
              ValidUntil)
    )
  )
```